# extract age group and cities visited of users tripadvisor python

Tags: python, web-scraping, extract, review, tripadvisor

I am struggling to scrape the age and number of cities visited of user at review section from tripadvisor using python. Please see the photo.
[image]

Please use the link: https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Hotel_Review-g56003-d266157-Reviews-Magnolia_Hotel_Houston-Houston_Texas.html
Not all of users provided their age group.
This is the codes I have been working on so far..

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url ='https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Hotel_Review-g56003-d266157-Reviews-Magnolia_Hotel_Houston-Houston_Texas.html'
info = browser.find_element_by_class_name('memberOverlayLink')
users_info = WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "memberOverlayLink")))
info.click()    
for photo in reviewBox.find_elements_by_class_name('innerContent'):
    age_group = ''
    try:
       age = photo.find_element_by_class_name("memberdescriptionReviewEnhancements li+ li")
       age_group = age.text
       age_group = ' '.join(age_group.split()[0:1])
    except NoSuchElementException:
       age_group = ''
    cities_visited = ''
    try:
       visit = photo.find_element_by_class_name("badgeTextReviewEnhancements")
       cities_visited = visit.text
       cities_visited = ' '.join(age_group.split()[0:1])
    except NoSuchElementException:
       cities_visited = ''
    close = reviewBox.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x")
    close.click()
```

Please anyone has any idea how to scrape them, please direct me. Thank you!.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Mihai: I can click to open the frame, and just stop right there. I am not able to extract the content (age, cities visited) and it just open the frame of the first user.

Comment: Post the code you're using and a specific problem that allows for a specific answer. Asking someone to write all the code for you from scratch is not what stack overflow is intended for. You also asked this same question yesterday and already got an answer.

Comment: @Mihai: I edited with the codes.

Comment: Because I found that, even with double click on the username, I'm still unable to scrape the data, because it is in another iframe.